# Нужны ли в этих предложениях запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

1. *Однообразный сложный* день.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Дискуссионные примеры. Их разбор полезен всем, а не только автору вопроса. Мне тоже хочется услышать мнения наших участников. Нужно не только выбрать знак, но и правильно обосновать.

Comment: Однообразный, но сложный день, - лучше так писать. Воздушный пышный бисквит - плеоназм какой-то.

Comment: Последнее предложение я увидела в учебнике по русскому .Тогда и возникли вопросы

Answer (score 2):

***Однообразный сложный день?***

Скорее всего, это **ошибка составителей,** и в действительности  там должен быть другой вариант: ***однообразный, утомительный день*** (также: *трудный, долгий*).

***Сложный*** и ***однообразный***  —  понятия скорее взаимоисключающие, что видно по словарю: [сложный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x), [однообразный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Соответственно, они не могут быть **общими** (однородными или неоднородными) определениями к одному предмету.

***Однообразный, но сложный день?***  Пожалуй, так тоже не скажешь. Сложный — это обладающий как раз **многообразными** и противоречивыми качествами, свойствами.

Поэтому такое сочетание можно оценить как **оксюморон**.  Например: *Каждый день для него был сложным и поэтому утомительным — так потянулись эти **однообразные сложные дни**.*  Определения **неоднородные**:   сложные дни, которые стали восприниматься как однообразные.

Comment: Спасибо большое